# How to get next to last MAX date with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a query in MS SQL to show items that have been in our "service center" more than once within the last 30 days. The data needed is from the service order prior to the most recent service order, based on serial number. So if an item has been received in the last 30 days, check to see if it was received at a previous time within the last 30 days.

ServiceOrders table: `CustID`, `ItemID`, `DateReceived`
ItemMaster table: `CustID`, `ItemID`, `SerialNumber`

I can get DateReceived items by using

```
ServiceOrders.DateReceived >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
```

I could load service orders from the past month into a temp table, and then query against that to get the prior service order, but that doesn't sound like the best plan. Any ideas on an efficient way to get the previous service orders?

Example data
    ServiceOrders table:

```
CustID  ItemID  DateReceived  
1       2       9/26/2016  
1       2       9/05/2016  
1       2       1/15/2015
5       6       9/20/2016
7       6       9/02/2016
```

ItemMaster table:

```
CustID  ItemID  SerialNumber  
1       2       8675309
5       6       101
7       6       101
```

So in the above example, SerialNumber 8675309 and 101 have been received more than once in the last 30 days. I need the data from ServiceOrders and ItemMaster for the DateReceived 9/05/2016 and 09/02/2016 records (the second most recent within 30 days). There are other fields in both tables, but they're simplified here. CustID won't necessarily stay the same from date to date, as the item can be transferred. SerialNumber is the key.

Comment: Post enough sample data to illustrate your task and the desired result.

Comment: I agree with PM 77-1. It would be really helpful if you could post some sample data to show what it is you're really after.

Comment: Added example data and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the last month orders  into Common Table Expression into cte and number them descending. Then select those items with more than 1 occurrences into cte2, join both cte's selecting the second row.

```
;With cte as(
  Select row_number() over(PARTITION  by ItemID order by DateReceived desc) as RowNum, * 
from ServiceOrders 
where DateReceived >= DateAdd(Month, -1, Getdate())
), cte2 as(
   Select 
  ItemID From cte
  Group by ItemID
  Having count(*)>1
)
 select b.*, c.SerialNumber from cte2 as a
 left join cte as b on a.ItemID= b.ItemID and b.RowNum=2
 left join ItemMaster as c on b.ItemID=c.ItemID and b.CustID=c.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `SELECT *, COUNT(ServiceOrders.DateReceived) as DateCount FROM TABLE`
2. Paste to excel
3. Filter last column to show results = or > than 2

Might be a quick solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the items which have been received more than once in the last 30 days. Then use `row_number` to number the rows based on the descending order of date_received. Finally, get the rows whose row_number is 2 (the date before the latest date in the last 30 days).

If serialnumber is needed in the output, just `join` the itemmaster table to the final resultset.

```
WITH morethanone
AS (SELECT
  so.itemid
FROM serviceorders so
JOIN itemmaster i
  ON i.itemid = so.itemid
GROUP BY so.itemid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, so.datereceived, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN 1 END)>1
)
SELECT
  custid,
  itemid,
  datereceived
FROM (SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY datereceived DESC) rn
FROM serviceorders
WHERE itemid IN (SELECT itemid FROM morethanone)
AND DATEDIFF(dd, datereceived, GETDATE()) <= 30
) x
WHERE rn = 2
```